# Don't show signature in a popup automatically

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to not have this popup automatically

[image]

?

But rather have it popup only when pressing `ctrl + space` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Put `"editor.parameterHints.enabled": false` in *settings.json*

And then the hint can be triggered by the "Trigger Parameter Hints" command.

Which by default is bound to `ctrl + shift + space`